# Как получить результат с Activity когда вызывается Галерея и нет

Tags: java, android

Всем привет!

Я с одного активити вызываю Галерею и получаю ответ.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);

        switch (requestCode) {
            case GALLERY_REQUEST:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                    try {
                        bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), selectedImage);
                        send = true;
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    ivPhoto.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }
        }
    }
```

Приходит `Intent imageReturnedIntent`
но теперь хочу вызвать другую активити и получить ответ но там

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
```

ответ приходит `Intent data`

Как объеденить?
Спасибо

Comment: вы не знаете как intent использовать при переходе на другое activiti?

Comment: наверное нет, если знал бы то написал бы вопрос? )

Comment: используйте разный requestCode при вызове startActivityForResult